# Need help in stacking font-awesome icons

Tags: css, font-awesome

I recently upgraded the `font-awesome` version from `3.2.1` to `4`.

I had this working in `3.2.1`

```
<li><span class="icon-stack stacked"><i class="icon-circle icon-stack-base"></i><i class="icon-phone icon-2x icon-light">
</i></span><span class="stacktext">Your Phone Number</span></li>

 .stacked
 {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: #3ECCFC;
 }

.stacktext
{
  text-align:left;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444444;
}
```

But it is not stacking up well in `version 4`.

```
<li><span class="fa fa-stack stacked"><i class="fa fa-circle fa fa-stack-base"></i><i class="fa fa-phone icon-2x fa fa-light">
        </i></span><span class="stacktext">Your Phone Number</span></li>
```

Comment: Could you show us code of what you have done in Font Awesome 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only have to use the class `fa` once in a `class=""`. I've updated several bits in your code.

Define the main stack size in the `<span>` around the `<i>` elements. `stacked` is obsolete in Font Awesome 4, since `fa-stack` defines a stack too. Also `fa-light` is changed to `fa-inverse`. At last `fa-stack-1x` and `fa-stack-2x` are used to scale the icons in the stack. `fa-stack-2x` will be used to make an icon larger compared to the other icon in the stack.

**Everything put together results in:**

```
<li>
   <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-phone fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
   </span>
   <span class="stacktext">Your Phone Number</span>
</li>
```

Please check the examples of stacks given on the Font Awesome website: [Stacks](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/).

Comment: And how the hell do you resize this?

Answer (score 0):

The `icon-` class prefix become `fa fa-` :

> icon-* -> fa fa-*

Source: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.2.1-to-4